# Correct time sum in no UTC timezone

Tags: c++, time, mfc, timespan

I am programming MFC with Visual Studio 2010 in Central Europe.

I have 2 time picker that i use to get the duration of two different jobs
and I get on my code the time setted in these control using a CTime variable.

I also have an edit control that have to display the sum of the 2 pickers previously setted.

My code is the following:

```
CTime       TimeJob1;
CTime       TimeJob2;

CTimeSpan   CTSTotalJobsTime, CTSJob1, CTSJob2;

m_DTP_Job1.     GetTime(TimeJob1);
m_DTP_Job2.     GetTime(TimeJob2);

CTSJob1 = TimeJob1 - CTime(0);
CTSJob2 = TimeJob2 - CTime(0);

CTSTotalJobsTime = CTSJob1 + CTSJob2;

CString strTotalJobsTime = CTSTotalJobsTime.Format(_T("%H:%M:%S"));
m_EditTotalJobsTime.SetWindowText(strTotalJobsTime);
```

When I edit the time picker control and calc the sum of the two times, it seems like if I have an offset of 1 hour.

I try to explain in a better way.

If I set the duration of the first job to 01:00:00 and of the second job 01:00:00 the sum of the time in the edit control is 00:00:00.

If I set the duration of the first job to 02:00:00 and of the second job 02:00:00 the sum of the time in the edit control is 01:00:00.

If I set the duration of the first job to 05:00:00 and of the second job 01:00:00 the sum of the time in the edit control is 04:00:00.

If I set the duration of the first job to 02:00:00 and of the second job 04:00:00 the sum of the time in the edit control is 01:00:00.

I suppose is a problem due to the difference between my system time (UTC+1) and the UTC time of the Time(0).

Am I wrong? How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I initialize my time picker on OnInitDialog() in this way:

CTime timeTime(1970, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0);

```
m_DTP_Job1->SetTime(&timeTime);
m_DTP_Job2->SetTime(&timeTime);
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zb0ese.aspx#ctime__ctime) states "A `__time64_t` time value, which is the number of seconds after January 1, 1970 UTC. Note that this will be adjusted to your local time." Have you tried any of the other constructors?

Comment: To retrieve the current system date and time in local time, use the GetLocalTime function. Don't mix system time with UTC time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS MY SOLUTION:**

I tried to use CTimeSpan and the date time picker control, but i see that they don't work for me because CTimeSpan parameter are day, hours, minutes, second while i use the date time picker only for time (no days).

So when i set the hours at 00, thanks to UTF automatic conversion, my CTimeSpan change day to the previose one and set the hours to 23.

So, i decided to delete the date time picker and use 3 differnt CEdit for hours, minutes, second.